# How to bind Database column name to GridView TemplateField HeaderText dynamically?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I am facing some problem in asp.net to do some task dynamically. 
          I want to take database table column name as header name in my gridview.So that i can name my gridview dynamically.

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"  AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="SteelBlue" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

         <Columns >
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DCName">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtDCName" Text='<%# Eval("DCName") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StartDate">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" Text='<%# Eval("StartDate") %> ' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EndDate">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" Text='<%# Eval("EndDate") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblDCId" Text='<%# Eval("DCId") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>              
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you can achieve that in `RowDataBound` property of gridview

Comment: i want to bind my database table column name with <TemplateField> HeaderText.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?

```
         <asp:TemplateField >
         <HeaderTemplate >
         <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'></asp:Label>     
         </HeaderTemplate>
         .......
```

Comment: here "title" is also a column name... but somehow i want to use this "title"  the text.

Comment: I dont know if i am understanding.You want to use just an assigned text as the Header? If thats the case put Text="Title"

Comment: i want the header txt should be changed according to the database table column id